# Registros afectados con SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql

tengo el siguiente método:

```
        public void ExeNonQuery()
    {

        using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(Connexio()))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(_Query, sql))
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                _AffRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }

    }
```

Pero _Affrows siempre es 0, alguien puede ayudarme ?
Decir que si, hay registros afectados.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Incluye el contenido de `sql`

Comment: que query estas ejecutando? hay alguna opcion de la DB que impida el recuento de datos afectados?

Comment: Según la documentación (https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_ExecuteNonQuery) si te devuelve 0 es que no está afectando a ningún registro. ¿Puedes compartir la consulta SQL que estás realizando?

Answer (score 0):

Según [la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_ExecuteNonQuery), no hay vuelta de hoja, el código es correcto

> Aunque el ExecuteNonQuery no devuelve ninguna fila, los parámetros de salida o los valores devueltos asignados a los parámetros se rellenan con datos.
>
> En el caso de las instrucciones UPDATE, INSERT y DELETE, el valor devuelto es el número de filas afectadas por el comando. Para todos los demás tipos de instrucciones, el valor devuelto es -1.

Solo faltaría conocer el tipo de datos de la variable `_AffRows` que debería ser **un entero**. Prueba de hacerlo de esta forma, con el `SqlCommand` dentro del `SqlConnection`, aunque el ámbito es el mismo que utilizando el `using`.

```
using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(Connexio()))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(_Query, sql);
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    _AffRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Aunque lo más probable es que la sentencia con la que has probado no afecta a ningún registro.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente lo que estás tratando de hacer es poner directamente la instrucción o sentencia SQL en el método (en la variable `sql`), eso te traerá siempre cero dado que no devuelve ningún valor, a menos que se lo pidas, puedes probar ponerlo en un bloque anónimo si no tienes un Procedimiento Almacenado, no lo he probado pero podría funcionar, quedaría algo así:

```
BEGIN
 UPDATE
    tabla
 SET
    Campo = 'Otro dato'
 WHERE
    id = 1 -- Esto es un ejemplo de update

 SELECT
    @@ROWCOUNT AS filasAfectadas
END
```

En tu código de SQL debe haber algo parecido a ésto:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.tusp
--  PARAMETROS   --  
AS  
BEGIN  
 SET NOCOUNT ON
 DECLARE @devolverValor INT
 /*
 Si hiciste un Insert y quieres conocer el Id generado
 */
 INSERT INTO
    tabla
   (Campo)
 VALUES
   ('Dato')

 SET @devolverValor = @@IDENTITY

 SELECT
    @devolverValor AS valorDevuelto
END
```

Este se apega más a lo que buscas obtener, los registros afectados:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.tuspactualizado
--  PARAMETROS   --  
   @id INT
AS  
BEGIN  
 SET NOCOUNT ON
 DECLARE @filasAfectadas INT

 UPDATE
    tabla
 SET
    Campo = 'Otro dato'
 WHERE
    id = @id

 SET @filasAfectadas = @@ROWCOUNT

 SELECT
    @filasAfectadas AS filasAfectadas
END
```

---

**Actualización:**

Intenta estructurarlo de esta forma para asegurar que te devuelva el resultado con el SqlHelper. Fuente: [SqlCommand Class (Microsoft)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=netframework-4.8#examples)

```
   static void AddCredits(String connectionString, Int32 creditsLow) {  
      String commandText = "Update [MySchool].[dbo].[Course] Set Credits=Credits+1 Where Credits<@Credits";  

      SqlParameter parameterCredits = new SqlParameter("@Credits", creditsLow);  

      Int32 rows = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(connectionString, commandText, CommandType.Text, parameterCredits);  

      Console.WriteLine("{0} row{1} {2} updated.", rows, rows > 1 ? "s" : null, rows > 1 ? "are" : "is");  
   }
```

Comment: Esto es solamente si utlizara parametros de retorno. El objeto que usa para hacer el query devuelve la cantidad de registros afectados. El problema no es por aca.

Comment: No va a devolver una fila completa, sólo el escalar que está queriendo recibir en la variable ```_AffRows```

Comment: mira la documentacion de ExecuteNonQuery. solo devuelve el numero de filas afectadas, los parametros de retorno estan en otro lado.

Comment: Tienes razón @gbianchi, he consultado y efectivamente debería devolver los registros afectados, he actualizado la respuesta esperando que el método de ejemplo ayude a resolverlo